# what is slonik in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, slony

**myfile**

```
#INIT CLUST
cluster name = lol ; 
 node 1 admin conninfo=''; 
 node 2 admin conninfo=''; 

EXECUTE SCRIPT ( 
FILENAME = './sql_statements.sql',
 EVENT NODE = 1
);
```

Then in a .sh script a line as:

```
slonik myfile;
```

What is the meaning of above code ?

Comment: [Slonik](https://github.com/gajus/slonik) is a Node.js PostgreSQL client.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logo Slonik is also the Mascot,    an overloaded elephant

Answer (score 0):

[Slony](http://www.slony.info/) is a master-slave replication for earlier versions of postgres as starting from version 9 a similar tool is available out of box.

Answer (score 0):

[`slonik`](http://www.slony.info/documentation/2.2/slonik.html) is the command line interface of Slony-I.

Slony is a trigger-based replication solution from the days before streaming replication and logical replication. It still is useful in more complicated replication scenarios.

This command file will execute the script `sql_statements.sql` on all nodes in a Slony cluster in a coordinated fashion.